# In a topological space, can an open set be homeomorphic to a non-open set? Why or why not?

Tags: general-topology

So given a topological space $X$ where $\mathcal{T}$ is its topology. Suppose $A$ is an subset of $X$ which is not in $\mathcal{T}$ but it's possible to define a subspace topology on $A$ and we can call it $\mathcal{T}_A$. Similarly, one can define a subspace topology $\mathcal{T}_B$ on an set $B\in\mathcal{T}$. The question is whether there exists a homeomorphism between $(A,\mathcal{T}_A)$ and $(B,\mathcal{T}_B)$

To be specific, I'm considering the case where $B$ is a connected neighborhood in $R^2$ and $A$ is the closure of $B$.

Comment: What is the definition of a homeomorphism?

Comment: Like the usual definition in terms of continuity.

Comment: But the continuity is terms of the subspace topology.

Comment: @ThomasShelby: The homeomorphism may not extend across the entire space.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the topological space $\{ 0 \} \cup [1, \infty)$ with the subspace topology from the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$.  In this topological space, $\{ 0 \}$ is open but $\{ 2 \}$ is not.

Comment: What if I add a restriction where the isolated point is not allowed?

Comment: Then you could modify the counterexample - for example, consider the subspace $[0, 1] \cup (4, 7)$ of $\mathbb{R}$ where $[0, 1]$ is open but $[5, 6]$ is not.

Comment: Okay, I see. I'm actually considering a more specific case stated in the question. Do you think that's possible in that case?